# Select entire row as well as third highest salary

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to fetch all row details of user with third highest salary.

My query

```
select min(salary)as minsalary from (select * from userdetails 
        order by salary desc limit 3) as details
```

Current output :-

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [minsalary] => 300
    )

)
```

i need to fetch the full row details too along with this array as single array output. How can i alter my query.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT * FROM userdetails ORDER BY salary DESC limit 2,1;
```

Another way to find `nth Highest salary` could be:-

```
SELECT * FROM userdetails usr1
WHERE (n-1) = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(usr2.salary )) 
    FROM  userdetails usr2 
    WHERE usr2.salary > usr1.salary )
```

Comment: thank you so much, may i know how the second query works, do we need to pass the value of n dynamically?

Comment: For each record for outer query, Inner query gets executed and will return how many records has salary less than the current salary. As you are looking for 3rd highest salary,it will stop as soon as inner query returns 2 (3-1);